# When does the compiler move/copy in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to better understand how moving works in C++. How does the compiler know when to move and when not to move?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Container {
    T value;
    Container (T value): value(value) {}
    Container (const Container & i): value(i.value) {
        std::cout << "copying" << std::endl;
    }
    Container (Container && i): value(std::move(i.value)) {
        std::cout << "moving" << std::endl;
    }
};

void increment (Container<int> n) {
    std::cout << "incremented to " << ++n.value << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    Container<int> n (5);
    increment(std::move(n));
    std::cout << n.value << std::endl;
}
```

This example prints

```
moving
incremented to 6
5
```

So I'd expect the `int` to have been moved, but then I shouldn't be able to still use it afterwards (and get the original value).

OK, so maybe the `int` was copied because `value(std::move(i.value))` copied it in the move constructor. But I still don't understand why `Container<int> n` is still around after it's definitely been moved.

Comment: Note that with optimizations, your output statements might never be shown due to the fact that side-effects in a copy-constructor (and I believe also a move constructor) can be ignored.

Comment: "So I'd expect the `int` to have been moved, but then I shouldn't be able to still use it afterwards" Why not? Should the compiler trash it with junk data, and every other primitive type that gets `std::move`d, just to line up with your mistaken definition of move semantics? That would represent an anti-optimisation. Moving exists to enable optimal transfer of resources. Primitive types by definition don't have any resources.

Comment: @rubenvb that's true, but not in _all_ circumstances. Eg for intialisation and for function returns copy elision is allowed. But, I do not believe it would be allowed in OP's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'd expect the int to have been moved, but then I shouldn't be able to still use it afterwards (and get the original value).

A "move" in C++ doesn't actually move memory. For complex types like strings and vectors, a "move" means the internal pointers are swapped over rather than copying all the pointed-to data. But for an `int`, there's no short-cut that can be done so the data is simply copied. That's why your original value is still there, and you can still read it.

> How does a C++ compiler know when to move and when not to move?

It doesn't!

The author of the moveable class does. Typically, you put this "pointer swap" logic into a "move constructor", which is a fancy name for a constructor taking an rvalue-reference. The overload resolution rules since C++11 were designed so that this constructor will be invoked whenever you pass in a temporary (or pass in an rvalue that you got through cheating, by writing `std::move` (which is terribly named as it does not move anything!)), because these are the sorts of objects you usually want to "move from".

But if you don't write any "move" code in the move constructor then the compiler isn't going to invent some for you.

> But I still don't understand why `Container<int> n` is still around after it's definitely been moved.

You didn't write any code that, after passing it to a move constructor, would leave the original `Container<int>` in any different state.

Again, the move constructor doesn't automatically do anything like that. It's just a place for *you* to put *your* moving logic!

Here's an alternative version of `Container` for which moving *would* be observable:

```
template <typename T>
struct Container
{
    T* ptr;
    Container(T value) : ptr(new T(value)) {}
    Container(const Container& i): ptr(new T(*i.ptr)) {
        std::cout << "copying" << std::endl;
    }
    Container(Container&& i) {
        ptr = i.ptr;
        i.ptr = nullptr;
        // no data copied - we just "steal" the data by swapping pointers!
        std::cout << "moving" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Container() { delete ptr; }
};
```

(I've used raw pointers to be as clear as I can about what's going on; in reality you'd use a `std::unique_ptr` which actually does the same thing for you in its *own* move constructor!)

Answer (score 6):

`std::move` really just changes a value into an rvalue, which can be moved. If you apply this to an `int` it has no real effect, since it doesn't make any sense to "move" an `int` value. (It's true that the value is still an rvalue; it's just that having an rvalue reference to an `int` is generally no more useful than having any other kind of reference to an `int`).

This is because *moving* is meant to be about transferring resources from one object to another, in such a way that the need to duplicate those resources (by copying them) is avoided - because such duplication can be non-trivial; it might require dynamic memory allocation, for one thing. Copying an `int` value is trivial, so there is no need for special move semantics.

So, applied to your example, moving the `Container<int>` is exactly the same as copying it, except of course for the output ("moving" vs "copying").

(Note that even a *move* requires the source object to remain in a valid state after the operation completes - it doesn't destroy the source object, as you seem to think that it perhaps should).

As to how the compiler knows when it can move vs copy, this is a matter of the *type category*. Your use of `std::move` specifically changes the value's type category to *rvalue* (or more specifically to *xvalue*) and this type of value can match the rvalue reference parameter in your move constructor. In general, overloads with rvalue reference parameters are preferred to those with non-rvalue reference parameters (the precise rules are complex).

The other common way of producing an rvalue is as an unnamed temporary - by performing some operation on an object or value where the result isn't bound to a variable (`a + b`, where `a` and `b` are both of type `int`, is a simple example - the result is a temporary object; it doesn't exist in a variable of its own). When a more complex object is a temporary, moving it into its final destination can be more efficient than copying it, and is safe since the indeterminate state of the moved-from object cannot be used afterwards. So, such values are also rvalues and will bind to rvalue references (and may be moved).

Comment: Wording quibble. It doesn't change a reference into an rvalue reference. It changes an lvalue into an xvalue, just preserves prvalue-ness.

Comment: @Barry `std::move` is equivalent to using a `static_cast` to an rvalue reference type, so in this sense changes (or rather, I suppose, converts) a reference to an rvalue reference. In my eyes the important thing - especially with regards to this example - is that the result is an rvalue reference and will bind to an rvalue reference parameter (such as in the move constructor). Whether or not is an xvalue is not important.

Comment: @Barry (however, I've updated the answer - since you're right, it's more correct to say "changes into an rvalue" than to an "rvalue reference").

Answer (score 3):

> So I'd expect the int to have been moved

Primitive types like `int` have no move constructor, they are simply copied.

> but then I shouldn't be able to still use it afterwards

That is not how moving works. You can still use a moved-from object just fine - it will be in a valid state. However, that state is indeterminate, so you cannot expect the object to have any specific value, nor can you use operations that have preconditions. There are no operations on `int` objects that have preconditions as far as I am aware.

> OK, so maybe the int was copied because value(std::move(i.value)) copied it in the move constructor.

Yes, it was copied.

> But I still don't understand why Container n is still around after it's definitely been moved.

Objects do not disappear after being moved from. In general, they are left in a valid, but indeterminate state. This particular move constructor that you wrote happens to leave the object in exactly the same state as it was before being moved from.

---

> When does the compiler move ... in C++

When copy-initialization is called with a non-const rvalue argument *and* the type of the object has a move constructor. Or when an object is assigned with a non-const r-value operand, and the type of the object has a move assignment operator.

> How does the compiler know when to move and when not to move?

The compiler knows the types of all expressions. In particular, it knows whether the type of an expression is a non-const rvalue or not. The compiler also knows definitions of all types that you can move. Based on the definition, the compiler knows whether a type has a move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A move only makes sense for objects that have non trivial state that it would be expensive to copy. At the end of a move both the original value and the new value should be in a valid state. The new value should be equivalent to what the old value was, and you generally have no idea what the old values state is other than being valid.

As an example, with a vector, copying the content from one to the other is expensive, so a move would just swap the contents. This is much more efficient, and has the bonus that it cannot fail. After the move, you can still use the old vector, but it won't be in the same state it was before the move.

Answer (score 0):

Once an object has been moved, there is nothing in the standard that says you cannot use it afterwards.  Top C++ developers, such as Sean Parent, have complained about this and want something "better" enforced by the standard.  Moving an object is intended as an optimization and can leave the moved object in any state.  As such, moving a primitive can be implemented by the compiler as a straight copy, leaving the original value alone.

To get a better idea of how moving an object works without writing some complicated object, just use a std::vector populated with a few values.  In the first call, we are establishing a base case.  The vector is passed by reference to a const so the copy constructor is called on the function's argument.  In the second call, the vector is passed as an rvalue reference because we casted it as such when we call std::move.  In this case the vector's move constructor is going to be invoked.  Internally, the new value (the function's argument) is taking the internal pointers from the passed in rvalue reference for itself.  It then sets the passed in vector's internal pointers to something similar of an empty vector.  We see this in the third call where we make another copy.  However, the vector was moved in the second call and therefore has no elements in it for the third call's copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_size(std::vector<int> value) {
    std::cout << value.size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::cout << "Pass by reference to const: ";
    print_size(v);
    std::cout << "Pass by rvalue reference: ";
    print_size(std::move(v));
    std::cout << "Pass by reference to const: ";
    print_size(v);
    return 0;
}
```